# How to make a single query with multiple records

Tags: 7, database

How do I make this as a single query?

```
$result = db_query("SELECT replace(source, 'node/', '') as source FROM {url_alias}  where source like 'node/%' limit 11");
foreach ($result as $record) {
$result2 = db_query("SELECT fci.* FROM {node} AS fci LEFT JOIN {node_access} AS fdfp ON fci.nid = fdfp.nid where fci.nid = :item_id AND fdfp.nid IS NULL", array(':item_id' => $record->source));
  foreach ($result2 as $record2) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($record2);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is purely programming question that simply happen to origin from Drupal context. You probably will have better luck finding query gurus at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$result2 = db_query("SELECT fci.* FROM {node} AS fci LEFT JOIN {node_access} AS fdfp ON fci.nid = fdfp.nid where fci.nid IN(SELECT replace(source, 'node/', '') as source FROM {url_alias}  where source like 'node/%') AND fdfp.nid IS NULL");
foreach ($result2 as $record2) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($record2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using any of the fields contained in the node_access table, and you are making a `LEFT JOIN` with that table, you can avoid to join with that table. I would rather rewrite the query as follows, supposing that you want to get only the nodes with a path alias.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT n.* FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {url_alias} ua ON ua.source = CONCAT('node/', n.nid)");
foreach ($result as $record) {
  dpm($record->title);
}
```

If then you want to get all the nodes with a path alias to which the currently logged-in user has access, I would use the following code.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n');
$query->join('url_alias', 'ua', "ua.source = CONCAT('node/', n.nid)");
$query->addTag('node_access');
$result = $query->execute();
foreach ($result as $record) {
  dpm($record->title);
}
```